# XSLT conditional variable assignment of XML document

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, conditional-statements, document

In my XSLT stylesheet I wish to assign an XML document object to a global variable. The name of the XML document varies so the assignment should be conditional. The names of the different XML documents are as follows: screenlabels0.xml, screenlabels1.xml, etc. The number in these names is equal to the value of a parameter ui_language passed to the stylesheet. As long as I hard code the assignment as follows, this works fine:

```
<xsl:variable name="screenlabels" select="document('..\xslt\screenlabels1.xml')"/>
```

Later in the stylesheet I can address nodes from this object via an Xpath starting with $screenlabels (no need to apply node-set to it).
Any attempt to condionalize this has failed so far. 
First I notice that the following code apparently is not equal to the single line of code above:

```
  <xsl:variable name="screenlabels">
    <xsl:value-of select="document('..\xslt\screenlabels1.xml')"/>
  </xsl:variable>
```

It seems I cannot address this variable the same way, nor after applying node-set to it. Changing value-of to copy-of doesn't seem to help either. A conditional variant to the above using a choose construction then doesn't work either of course.
My alternative approach to simply use the ui_language parameter in the single-line assignment, like below, didn't work either. Anyone any ideas how to do this or have I been sloppy in my testing? Your help would be appreciated greatly.

```
<xsl:variable name="screenlabels" select="document('..\xslt\screenlabels{$ui_language}.xml')"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried `concat`?

```
<xsl:variable name="screenlabels" 
     select="document(concat('..\xslt\screenlabels',$ui_language,'.xml'))"/>
```